# Removing the extra space in between date and time in excel

Tags: excel, date, time, space

How do you remove the extra space between the date and time in excel? It automatically formats to `2/17/2017  18:49`; I need it to be formatted to `2/17/20174 18:49` in a CSV file I am uploading to a program.

Comment: Format the column (select column then Ctrl+1) as `m/d/yyyy hh:mm`.

Comment: I have tried this it always puts in 2 spaces in the format even if I only have 1 space in the m/d/yyyy hh:mm

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you simply change the number format to user-specific **M/D/YYYY hh:mm**?
In Excel 2007 - 2013 go to the Home tab and select in the "Number" Area the drop down menu "Number Format" for "user specific format. In Excel 2003 use Format -> Cells.

This worked for me even after exporting the file to CSV.

Comment: I have tried this it always puts in 2 spaces in the format even if I only have 1 space in the m/d/yyyy hh:mm

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, in the end i resorted to opening the file in Google sheets.
I found using Google Sheets that it didn't automatically add a double space, even though i opened the exact same file.

bit late but hope it helps